# Multiple Snackbars

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-snackbar

Is it possible to display, say, 2, 3 or 4 Snackbars (stacked) at the same time? I'm using the official Google Design and AppCompat support libraries right now, and would come handy (I'm using Snackbars to display status of the app - network status, power status, training mode, etc., which are all important information, have their own color, and I cannot concatenate them into one).

My snackbars right now are persistent, without action, and I do not plan to change this.

Comment: Not a duplicate. I want to display all Snackbars in one fragment, or to be more specific, in the same layout.

Comment: then you have to make customize snackbar

Comment: @fonix232 have you found a way to get this done?

Answer (score 8):

According to the [doc](https://material.google.com/components/snackbars-toasts.html) : "Only one snackbar may be displayed at a time."

Comment: I'm well aware of the design target limitations. However if you check my statement, I do say that I'm not exactly using it as intended :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. But not a snackbar. Just made your own recyclerview with wrap content height and attach it to a decor view of an activity.
Set gravity bottom.
Any item before removed from recyclerview will be part of.

Comment: Sounds simple enough for there to already be a library that does exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

you should use bottomsheet,so that you can achieve your desired output.[refer this link](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/bottom-sheet-android/)